# What are some approaches to run multiple Pig scripts sequentially?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I need to run some Pig scripts sequentially in Hadoop.  They must be run separately.  Any suggestions?

**update**

Just a quick update that we're working toward running the Pig scripts from one Java class.  Oozie is a possibility that was mentioned in a comment (though much too heavy for our needs).  I've also heard that it's possible to orchestrate Pig scripts as a part of a larger job flow in Cascading (http://www.cascading.org/) and looked at that a little.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple sequence of tasks I guess what orangeoctopus suggested would probably suffice. If you would like to club together a more complex workflow of pig and/or plain vanilla MapReduce, you should probably take a look at [Oozie](http://yahoo.github.com/oozie/)

**Update :**

If you are using pig 0.9, you could also possibly take a look at embedding pig in a language like python. Heres the [link](http://www.hortonworks.com/new-apache-pig-features-part-2-embedding/)

Answer (score 1):

In practice, I wrap the majority of my Pig scripts in bash scripts. You could control the sequential execution inside of the shell script:

`pig myscript1.pig && pig myscript2.pig && pig myscript3.pig`